# C# Mark method as called by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, sonarqube

I have a class whitch have methods called by reflection to call automatically them depending on execution environment.

I wanted to indicate that these methods are called by reflection because it seems not to be used to anyone who doesn't have knowledge of the application.

I have indicated it in the documentation section of the class but I want to ask if there is any better way also to avoid alerts of SonarQube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [`UsedImplicitlyAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#UsedImplicitlyAttribute) of JetBrains Annotations.

There is a [SonarQube ReSharper CLT Plugin](https://github.com/Soloplan/resharper-clt-plugin) that might help you.

Comment: What exactly does this annotation? Because I see it's from JetBrains but it seems that it's also in NuggetPackage. To configure Sonar its's the plugin neccesary?